# Gatling Scala:Unable to send auth token to the method using session variable

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

It seems session variable used in below code is not able to pass the Token Type --> Bearer and access_token using session variable,here is the full code ,is it possible with you to have a look ,here is code provided ..no worries all tokens are dummy tokens as i haven changed before pasting code here.Test expects the login method to be executed first and then the CreatePrivateEvent method as the latter takes tokens from Login method hence i have written

From Logs It looks Token Type --> Bearer and access_token are successfully generated by Login Method but the same token is not propagated to CreatePrivateEvent method.

any other way you can suggest to use session variable would be highly welcomed?

```
val scenario4 = scenario("Create Private Events ").exec(login).exec(createPrivateEvent())

package simulations

import baseConfig.BaseSimulation
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.session
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.math._
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.io.Source


class gamekeeper extends BaseSimulation {


  val uri2 = "https://api.platform.abc.com"


  val headers_3 = Map(
  "accept" -> "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  "cache-control" -> "no-cache",
   "origin" -> "https://myaccounts.wi.com",
   "pragma" -> "no-cache",
   "referer" -> "https://myaccounts.abc.com/login?redireretailer-   stage.abc.com%2F",
    "sec-fetch-mode" -> "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site" -> "same-site")


  val headers_10 = Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json","Authorization" -> "${token_type} +    
  ${access_token}" )

  val headers_PrivateEvent = Map(
   "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
    "Authorization" -> "${token_type} + ${access_token}"

 )

val usersDataSource=jsonFile("C:/Gatling2/gatling3james/src/gatling/resources/data/input-  
gamekeeper.json").circular
val nameDataSource=jsonFile("C:/Gatling2/gatling3james/src/gatling/resources/data/input-
gamekeeper-StringBody.json").random




 val source: String = Source.fromFile("C:/Gatling2/gatling3james/src/gatling/resources
 /data/input-gamekeeper.json").getLines.mkString
  def userCount: Int  = JsonPath.parse(source).read("$.[0].user")
 def testDuration: Int  = JsonPath.parse(source).read("$.[0].testDuration")
 def rampDuration: Int  = JsonPath.parse(source).read("$.[0].rampDuration")


  // print out the properties at the start of the test
  before {
  println(s"Running test with ${userCount} users")
    println(s"Ramping users over ${rampDuration} seconds")
  println(s"Total Test duration: ${testDuration} seconds")
  }



 def createPrivateEvent()={

    exec(http("Create Private Event")


      .post("https://api.tabletop-stage.tiamat-origin.cloud/dev/event-reservations-service
  /PrivateEvents")
      .headers(headers_PrivateEvent)


      .body(StringBody(
        """
          |{
          |  "eventId": 0,
          |  "name": "new Event",
          |  "description": "This event is gonna be uh-maaaazing",
          |  "format": "draft",
          |  "gamesToWin": 2
          |}
        """.stripMargin)).asJSON

      .check(status.in(200,201))
      .check(jsonPath(path="$.name").is("new Event"))
      .check(jsonPath(path="$.eventId").saveAs(key="eventId")))
      .exec{session=>println(session);session}
    .pause(1)

  }

  val login = exec( exec(http("PlatForm Auth Url")
  .post(uri2 + "/auth/oauth/token")
  .headers(headers_3)
  .formParam("grant_type", "password")
  .formParam("username", "automation-store-admin1@abc.com")
  .formParam("password", "c0Ba5PBdvVl2")
  .basicAuth("NznShwKmLPMErYkfuvyynfA9","r2Rgx89aCFTfjbj7TU59sL8q")
  .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").exists.saveAs("access_token"))
  .check(jsonPath("$.token_type").exists.saveAs("token_type")))



  )


  val scenario4 = scenario("Create Private Events ").exec(login).exec(createPrivateEvent())


 setUp(

scenario4.inject(
  nothingFor(5 seconds),
  rampUsers(userCount) over ( rampDuration ))
  .protocols(httpConf))
.maxDuration(testDuration)
}
```

Here is detailed Gatling console logs:-

```
            Running test with 10 users
            Ramping users over 2 seconds
            Total Test duration: 20 seconds
            Simulation simulations.gamekeeper started...

            ================================================================================
            2020-01-24 13:53:33                                           5s elapsed
            ---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
            > Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )


            ---- Create Private Events  ----------------------------------------------------
            [                                                                          ]  0%
                      waiting: 10     / active: 0      / done:0     
            ================================================================================

            13:53:35.197 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,3,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@65999bbf, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzQsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNCwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6IkY3VlNaWllEWkpHUk5EU1UzRlpRMjRLWFRZIiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.JiLiOolxFWWEg0Zz-lKMNrGrn2gLMGW3akuBREsiVfF09eITi768bZ9AbfgBHjH3Ubz2HQBFMu59597AefLiUH8cOwUjValp8Cf3ZjwqpkdrkQXAfYjs-8t2h-Xs6Df0uhEw3rit9XFqDvtudkw1JvdzCIqGFxO17spy9Nsd2sTFtVOkMh1nFyeBMTZfAVVHL3oy1b3FpgJqAvNqaDBxdkpIcQqVtJoxM5aYJ4o-GjeSDE9HPCSq1mM0Yww2yaj5GjHFbGDa9w_7G2xS7kHomHlRh20bw5FkFd0Sj70D_JpomD9ywYOHcWTFyQnZ2zeKBZCBhMk42Z8paR0YlOnKEQ, token_type -> Bearer),1579902814543,10,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)
            13:53:35.229 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,1,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@330ff641, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzQsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNCwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6IkxFVk1PN1NWWE5DVkRLTU1ZRUMzTVpLTENZIiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.plrBZLzb620EZ5e8dKH4xiBUJ0UkrtBUmE6gPU5HbsoC9JVchztWT4wFk-0TdQRXozMz70GifyPoGRzHhcIJllOIRr_y8BPppTpTcFRNAKp8GB2_x2PMiZmi8I37fnmIwhgTixZBiy_FTEcieJ7Ib47K7_aAZnx7sEs0wt39waUHoSdY8j8iAOO8EadzJCLPS_cH6bCZRl0vbNYLI2O0d3qVAwH3e4M_lznZtprBaNKNyVImKxCpM0a601DxrhjnJgEgyJvwNLJX_n2PxXHV9BPSUmF5V6yX_QHqnXmEmip3XQnJEYjYi1olyD1Uq3yn2vKy3X10W5YriMjSCSFq-w, token_type -> Bearer),1579902814144,123,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)
            13:53:35.230 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,2,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@3f4621ef, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzQsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNCwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6IlRFRUEyMlA2TFZDNlJNS1NTN0o2WTVTRTc0Iiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.V_EHIsy1d8012eeitMwFN12-57SiWqVW2QTsBZWnJm0kq-1hYe7XYZ7PvPXCsw0ZSmIrYuQCZtCXt2zKPmDEEAlJj3rRoD-SYAxVSyeNjFObn2VnvjXzv4iVwP9R1bU8Ufbysot2nQOCFVZ3u02hbWVkm-AJA9DWcJhgb03eaCyT4ZGsxBHr3PJtfG352ankjJg4ODTSuGMc1QvryrRwHRi-AbTyDt0Gz2hl77zURHAi09rEjmKn-my6CMCVGPC5kMNOZTeJUosF8TnIw4og-njL2Th1Z-vMy35Uv_uOiV883eIn3AupusX0o6OducEugPW_3F8SuAq2cMIHJYareA, token_type -> Bearer),1579902814342,43,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)
            13:53:35.294 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,4,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@4c762bfc, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzQsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNCwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6IlBERTZBRzQ0REJHVjVBNURRUEY2M1JRU1RJIiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.lq0zRb72CTU4YSuEG0fiLyuCtG1CGez3_aV3SUrtokGEdLDIw1EImztNH950CfABCQ6ngmxVZRzZdqJ5gm7gZLQcu4VTlS0uAFWfIN2vyejUJZuqbO3YJ9TfdNp4h49pLFTX52u6Xwi6r5f4K_FV0QnOitqhJtaKdxdA4Hll4pXr_V5J-fuV9l0Iw6tXrasTzzkIwXQQerCwk5AcsaA9oijQ-W2GS3eDdhtii4aJJKBWt0LGopD9-GlmJkpOPJ7MMVcNIN7m0gUILEhX2c8Ay3neVnbZjrVWSfQ2R5MIEyOczCQT9pVKordKmcGdp8VfCPoslg0_o3dp8xm9WAJVSw, token_type -> Bearer),1579902814743,3,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)
            13:53:35.514 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,5,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@56bbd1db, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzUsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNSwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6Ik42Q0NKQzNMRTVBRUZPMzQ1WElCS1JZV1ZRIiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.nP91KlPVDqiIl2yBaxXj_5YOuTJ_qegY7paeOl0mUOsRKo0orob-YwgS7is4beLur6grLlGZsV_BDOo5zbiMy3LKg-XNynq8Wr8k4yALDGuUP7T-SvbX_hGG8jP1-ZcLJ_GDA0_mFHEFy5O8wscM4Vmj0iPazqusSh7L1klP0KVcCpsHzq2OdFQZAV857qnEshWSd1J9UomSLQ496mnXx3sAnfVeCJmDoIOeln670TvJqOT2Fp5mO4ABqW8BRprZHF42bozCB6xiqjTA1E4oNVxCXegoFHG-zz2NcW7FbuJaQ0PRYkfPFnwRpbZaQPoMDdZp2ZWFAzT2hwV3O-V7zg, token_type -> Bearer),1579902814943,3,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)
            13:53:35.696 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,6,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@462648e4, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzUsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNSwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6Iks1S0NKVUlYVUZDUkRNRExUNE1CUlFLWlVRIiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.C6_ElcB9H8SbdfxcbGBdNA4qOlisFi9wuQnHO9F-_GHzG63GCM-cWHGxX1HF22Y3dhYO8iUvXYv2w0iFtJmi_jc-TZVKwsNbperZSUEPvZDZ2nxGQPbU8g7CqgW2a1Sb-NCsE_rt4TGOSmdVYyH5d2sjNMiiEDqjbTJ6CZVo5LLBngO2fzp3hoptQClEPI7a6Y3I18FTl3l3ghLsodKGNS272TQFT78vBd4JssNHlT3heKnIPLA0bmXvX0G2N6c7Qgbos2LB-C01rbAzGQOR_mIxhRJzxRmi7rVEup6WtjcPKmulAX0gfxumHiuY7bGs8tNK2BI6HAqfJp9arngfKA, token_type -> Bearer),1579902815143,2,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)
            13:53:35.866 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,7,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@1f5eb0d8, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQwNGMxYzYxNTkwNDBmZGRhN2FlYjI0ODViOWU0MTBlZDM0ZDJkMDgiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzUsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNSwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6IjZTR0lBTVdaVkZDSUhIRzJQNjRRU0JQUlJZIiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.S2jvg1jLJAftEeOXzqKhY5XQxHwk6y3L6mRcNwBs8dgeZDEcZLNS7_k1SMgIcovd_-ud9NFqqT2pmnPGjvreOP0yNwP6fgzs7e_RiD1OTCD61yHlwJUEFEAwz8JhT0iR-PSH1wtygvrj4D3y0dYR5SJQkZal7ocq13gJGbIH_gOSbqkVgjB2Z6wHGyR31E8t54JpkPYOuQcu_ULb8O3f6L85gJRbql0ZyLOoUyNSWbwLWYkvgwlTbDOAtTVd07pnB0NzaECTtKuVLpD2Ci-s8w89LTbcAJ-fywS0A8k_ocr1Yiu-G_rX-fxNKGLnAv9z_kV9sQ-JuV5KnFfGFoNAZw, token_type -> Bearer),1579902815341,3,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)
            13:53:36.016 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,8,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@38dc8850, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzUsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNSwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6IkFWNlhHQkNDNjVDQlRDT0JIUkZLRDVOUkdJIiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.k4_bK6wP5fnTx2sF95lZr1PnX99u1vxYItsAOcDprsrbJwsWaEpgVZ_EJdPueb5JFsQwkgGlwLr0tx47YaBUP06z4sdbHEuCZsCeqogRLAk_W3AYGe6rkyJkBeyehVInyONm3y2ztMa9ZIOauaxN1aOYofjXXHfrUdIUXVxLP8UtyfZ6XYAVIm_c6_9j4NDq6meBzJ-NRAO2BRTusqm12yNdo9OWUybKIZi_A7ITAFpwcUp-NKy1rjdnUv6nT73D7EWEJ_c57tDdrmYgYPtFFFXi8UXwz9JD-U8YMCFM8j1rIgsi1MRX5IwvQ_rnKuMTk8uE-LqwZS0mSiLKLmd52g, token_type -> Bearer),1579902815542,3,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)
            13:53:36.204 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,9,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@1b480c45, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzUsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNSwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6IlpTVFo1RzRGMk5EM0ZLUEtPRzVBTEpCSDM0Iiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.mvi_WusCY2aqjnUaJkhCdZwS3e4RGmch2dFHdMTzPCsggrn5_Mhjhlee4WQZPIUVHqqxUKhUTrpThar9OKspb5O8qQOZ9xASkMtapxNS3dQH4lz5sN-dTTnuEgOjRFtXgap1W0XKiBGa1TjbDYQQ57Y9cXG0Zl-UF6g7kHTjybygAhOv3rOdOPzOutOu8Pljkc_Il0a_Sv_t1A2n2p_LBwAVZwldI5y9lY5nNpGV-E693d5eNd-NAc_CLnOyTvyQQ2K36psGFkP2Zhy9Re2oGsD1iouQJcuPnZFeOGFxaNQSaiyc8IBC84snVdPxM8uvcO_7kryTIj2huKwXdG85QA, token_type -> Bearer),1579902815742,3,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)
            13:53:36.412 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Create Private Event' failed: status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401
            Session(Create Private Events ,10,Map(gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@61d1e6b7, access_token -> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjM0NmM4YTY1NTBlZGI5MDRjM2IyNWI3ODlmOTllNjU3ODA4MGJiOTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJOem5TaHdLbUxQTUVyWWtmdXZ5eW5mQTkiLCJleHAiOjE1Nzk5MDM3NzYsImlhdCI6MTU3OTkwMjgxNiwiaXNzIjoiNENVNlRCUENSWkdSTkVXRkROQTZDRkRQNTQiLCJzdWIiOiJZSlJEQUc2SDNCRlRYSkE0RlJCRVhVSFE1TSIsIndvdGMtbmFtZSI6ImF1dG9tYXRpb25TdG9yZUFkbWluMSM4ODU3NCIsIndvdGMtZG9tbiI6IndpemFyZHMiLCJ3b3RjLWdhbWUiOiJwbGF0Zm9ybSIsIndvdGMtZmxncyI6MSwid290Yy1yb2xzIjpbXSwid290Yy1wcm1zIjpbXSwid290Yy1zY3BzIjpbImZpcnN0LXBhcnR5Il0sIndvdGMtcGRnciI6Ikc0NFVSVTNGS1ZCQ0RQTTNKNVhEWktGVzZZIiwid290Yy1zZ3RzIjpbXSwid290Yy1zb2NsIjp7fX0.WwzKSRj7YjY5j9QHvPNgcIc96Z0IvYmfJQ6526UPESpwceuvV-e_ItZYEAvj9-cCT7LdwzcROiuGDK1fTTjCilFdFTdb2HLHunscj9DEP6zS89JDi6QAsMjoLcVeMgbRDwotV12i-lByHQspMfLxjuB3jTY1YtSyFrHR7xgXCIELsZm2hAWwhr7cgaYugk8Va8PhUopgnqxrFQP4mssUZzraRz9G7FbKhmegrdhJ1dDuNGSKpnZCo3EeE2G5BJYsZpo7nAEVBWI5lN_8QikblLC-NUahyiEbG0UC_Gjt2pIqk9sgbzT-zGH2MwHVru8GQZ3yakZhATsvs0F0r-uuTA, token_type -> Bearer),1579902815939,5,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$450/657998502@582153b5)

            ================================================================================
            2020-01-24 13:53:37                                           9s elapsed
            ---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
            > Global                                                   (OK=10     KO=10    )
            > PlatForm Auth Url                                        (OK=10     KO=0     )
            > Create Private Event                                     (OK=0      KO=10    )
            ---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
            > status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401                    10 (100.0%)

            ---- Create Private Events  ----------------------------------------------------
            [##########################################################################]100%
                      waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done:10    
            ================================================================================

            Simulation simulations.gamekeeper completed in 8 seconds
            Parsing log file(s)...
            Parsing log file(s) done
            Generating reports...

            ================================================================================
            ---- Global Information --------------------------------------------------------
            > request count                                         20 (OK=10     KO=10    )
            > min response time                                    123 (OK=311    KO=123   )
            > max response time                                    546 (OK=546    KO=359   )
            > mean response time                                   297 (OK=371    KO=224   )
            > std deviation                                        108 (OK=73     KO=86    )
            > response time 50th percentile                        325 (OK=348    KO=201   )
            > response time 75th percentile                        356 (OK=357    KO=296   )
            > response time 95th percentile                        475 (OK=512    KO=359   )
            > response time 99th percentile                        532 (OK=539    KO=359   )
            > mean requests/sec                                      5 (OK=2.5    KO=2.5   )
            ---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------
            > t < 800 ms                                            10 ( 50%)
            > 800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                   0 (  0%)
            > t > 1200 ms                                            0 (  0%)
            > failed                                                10 ( 50%)
            ---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
            > status.find.in(200,201), but actually found 401                    10 (100.0%)
            ================================================================================

            Reports generated in 1s.
            Please open the following file: C:\Gatling2\gatling3james\results\gamekeeper-1579902807997\index.html

            Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about `"Authorization" -> "${token_type} + ${access_token}"` ?

Usually the format is like this `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSU`.

So try `"Authorization" -> "${token_type} ${access_token}"`